# How do I install a SQL Server Java driver into a linux docker container?

Tags: java, sql-server, linux, docker, alpine-linux

The docker image definition below does not contain according to the documentation a SQL Server driver.

How can I install it?

Documentation:
https://github.com/camunda/docker-camunda-bpm-platform

Docker File

```
FROM alpine:3.10 as builder

ARG VERSION=7.12.0
ARG DISTRO=tomcat
ARG SNAPSHOT=true

ARG EE=false
ARG USER
ARG PASSWORD

RUN apk add --no-cache \
        ca-certificates \
        maven \
        tar \
        wget \
        xmlstarlet

COPY settings.xml download.sh camunda-tomcat.sh camunda-wildfly.sh  /tmp/

RUN /tmp/download.sh


##### FINAL IMAGE #####

FROM alpine:3.10

ARG VERSION=7.12.0

ENV CAMUNDA_VERSION=${VERSION}
ENV DB_DRIVER=org.h2.Driver
ENV DB_URL=jdbc:h2:./camunda-h2-dbs/process-engine;MVCC=TRUE;TRACE_LEVEL_FILE=0;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
ENV DB_USERNAME=sa
ENV DB_PASSWORD=
ENV DB_CONN_MAXACTIVE=20
ENV DB_CONN_MINIDLE=5
ENV DB_CONN_MAXIDLE=20
ENV DB_VALIDATE_ON_BORROW=false
ENV DB_VALIDATION_QUERY="SELECT 1"
ENV SKIP_DB_CONFIG=
ENV WAIT_FOR=
ENV WAIT_FOR_TIMEOUT=30
ENV TZ=UTC
ENV DEBUG=false
ENV JAVA_OPTS="-Xmx768m -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m"

EXPOSE 8080 8000

# Downgrading wait-for-it is necessary until this PR is merged
# https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it/pull/68
RUN apk add --no-cache \
        bash \
        ca-certificates \
        openjdk11-jre-headless \
        tzdata \
        tini \
        xmlstarlet \
    && wget -O /usr/local/bin/wait-for-it.sh \
      "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it/a454892f3c2ebbc22bd15e446415b8fcb7c1cfa4/wait-for-it.sh" \
    && chmod +x /usr/local/bin/wait-for-it.sh

RUN addgroup -g 1000 -S camunda && \
    adduser -u 1000 -S camunda -G camunda -h /camunda -s /bin/bash -D camunda
WORKDIR /camunda
USER camunda

ENTRYPOINT ["/sbin/tini", "--"]
CMD ["./camunda.sh"]

COPY --chown=camunda:camunda --from=builder /camunda .
```

Comment: JDBC drivers go in your classpath.

Comment: can you please specify more details, how do I need to install them using the docker file?

Comment: Sorry, no idea.  You typically just need the jar on your classpath.  You may need to do more research on your question.

Comment: Please add command with which you get that error (edit  the question!). I guess it is one from this section https://github.com/camunda/docker-camunda-bpm-platform#database-environment-variables since it requires postgresql docker image running too but I am only guessing.
And please delete Dockerfile from the question or change it with this github link https://github.com/camunda/docker-camunda-bpm-platform/blob/next/Dockerfile since it is exactly the same.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was able to make it work after several days.

Steps

1. Download JDBC Driver from Microsoft Site, Version 7.2, it will include 2 JAR FILES
2. Uncompress, and copy the file into your docker folder
3. Copy the file into the camunda LIB folder, this is not explained anywhere, but after a short chat with camunda docker git repo people, they adviced me to do that.

Only line needs to add in DOCKER file is:

```
#MSSQL SERVER JDBC DRIVER INSTALL
COPY mssql-jdbc-7.2.2.jre11.jar /camunda/lib/
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation you refer to, Microsoft SQL Server is not supported.

So while you could try some exercise of downloading the JDBC driver (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/download-microsoft-jdbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017) and then add it to the Docker image and the classpath:

```
COPY name_of_jdbc_driver.jar /camunda/mssqlserver.jdbc
env CLASSPATH=/camunda/mssqlserver.jdbc
```

It's more than likely that this won't work because the camunda software does not support MS SQL Server.

So you should consider simply using one of the other databases that they explicitly support. I'd recommend PostgreSQL for example. It's free (as in beer and speech) and you can use it in production if you want to.

If you're just looking to do some testing and don't need this in a production environment. The instructions you point to have a decent explanation on how to start PostgreSQL in a Docker container and then start the Camunda container that uses the PostgreSQL container as a database.

Comment: It seems that someone managed to make it work [Configuring camunda with sql server](https://forum.camunda.org/t/solved-configuring-camunda-with-sql-server/3452). Camunda internally uses JPA so in theory SQL server should work as well.

Comment: Good point. It can possibly work... but when the list of officially supported databases include open source ones that you can use for free, I would always go that route. You never know what might otherwise break.

Comment: that list of DBs is not supported by our legal and security teams, so MS SQL is the preferred choice